# How to add a dependecy not included in "$^"?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I think I might be doing sommething wrong, but I've been unable to figure out how to make that piece of Makefile work the way I'd like :

```
 $(NAME): S(OBJ) $(LDLIBS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

My purpose is that `$(NAME)` depends from my library, and update it if necessary. But is there a way to not include it (LDLIBS) in the $^ automatic variablesm while keeping it as a dependency ?

Thxs very much.

Comment: If you don't need it when linking then it shouldn't be a dependency in the first place.

Comment: Explain why you think your library is dependency if you don't want to link it.

Comment: Hum, I was'nt very clear. I do want to link it. However, my trouble is that the recipe is not the same depending of whether or not the library already exists : if it exists, make find it and expand the name to the actual path, giving the recipe : `gcc -L libpath files.o libpath/libfile -o target`

Comment: If it doesnt, it does not put the full library path, only -llibname. 
If i'm correct. the former is wrong, since it makes the linker take the full lib (is that well accurate ?),
So I would like to always have the latter. and still makes my target depend on the lib,

Comment: You want to always use the local library? Then say so, add `libfoo.a` to `LDLIBS`, not `-lfoo`.

Comment: Your makefile is written wrongly. It is creating a problem for you that
should never arise. You need to post all of if, or at least an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)